# Зачем делать отступы в редакторе при вставке кода?

Tags: поддержка, редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы парсер понял, что в этом месте ты пишешь код, а не текст.

Почувствуйте разницу

```
function(foo,bar){
  return foo*bar
}
```

function(foo,bar){
      return foo*bar
    }

Comment: Кстати код еще можно завернуть символами ``` (кнопка Ё в английской раскладке). Эффект тот же.

Comment: @Bogdan Я как раз так и делаю. А еще можно \` для одной строчки кода.

Comment: "тут должна быть неявная похвальба наличием мака, через указание того, что ` у нас не на ё" =)